# How to grid correctly when containment element has scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Please understand my English first !!!
I am doing dragging for a schedule project ! I have trouble in dragging element(Event) for updating event.I set half hour as one td with `50px` so I can easily drag with `grid [50,0]` .It is ok in current view element but after I drag into scrollable containment part the grid didn't take correct pixel ! How can I do correctly drag with gird in scrollable containment element !

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/22bpbsrw/31/)
[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I continually solving my question ! I got some possible answer myself ! I detected for incorrect grid when in scroll mode by `droppable drop` method! In that I check which `td` interval my drag element has reached and get nearest td offset .In that way I can solve my correct grid when dragging in scroll mode

```
$("tbody tr").droppable({
    drop:function(e,ui){        
        var same = false;
        $("td").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).offset().left +"=="+ $(ui.helper).offset().left);
            if($(this).offset().left == $(ui.helper).offset().left){
                same = true;
                return false;
            }           
        });
        if(same) {
            return false;
        }
        $("td").each(function(){
            if($(this).offset().left <= $(ui.helper).offset().left && $(ui.helper).offset().left <= $(this).next().offset().left){              
                $(ui.helper).css("left",$(this).offset().left - $(ui.helper).parent().offset().left);
                return false;
            }   
        });
    }
});
```